# Gap in \rule line using tcolorbox

Tags: latex

I'm using the package tcolorbox to create a document with two colored boxes.  I'd like to have a a line stretching all the way across the white portion of the document, but it seems like there is something preventing it from completely filling the width. How can I modify the page to get this line to stretch all the way across?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{margin=0pt}

\newtcolorbox{bgbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,leftright skip=0pt,boxrule=0pt,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,#1}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{navy}{RGB}{10, 35 63}
    \definecolor{gold}{RGB}{201, 151, 44}
    \noindent
    \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=navy,width=0.25\textwidth,rightrule=.05in,colframe=gold]
        \vspace{1.25in}
        \color{gold}\LARGE{\textsc{Contact}}\\
    \end{bgbox}%
    \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=white,width=0.75\textwidth,colframe=gold]
        \vspace{.25in}
        \begin{flushright}
            \Huge\color{navy} \textsc{Name}\\
            \LARGE Position\\
            \color{gold}\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.05in}
        \end{flushright}

    \end{bgbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to remove any padding of the `tcolorbox` is to use the `size=minimal` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{margin=0pt}

\newtcolorbox{bgbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,leftright skip=0pt,boxrule=0pt,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,#1}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{navy}{RGB}{10, 35 63}
    \definecolor{gold}{RGB}{201, 151, 44}
    \noindent
    \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=navy,width=0.25\textwidth,rightrule=.05in,colframe=gold]
        \vspace{1.25in}
        \color{gold}\LARGE{\textsc{Contact}}\\
    \end{bgbox}%
    \begin{bgbox}[height=\paperheight,colback=white,width=0.75\textwidth,colframe=gold,size=minimal]
        \vspace{.25in}
            \begin{minipage}{.95\linewidth}
                \flushright
                \Huge\color{navy} \textsc{Name}\\
              \LARGE Position\\
            \end{minipage}

            \color{gold}\rule[-1em]{\linewidth}{.05in}

    \end{bgbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]